# In WPF, How do I check a CheckBox based on a TextBox.Text value?

Tags: wpf

How do I check a CheckBox based on a TextBox.Text value?

I am have a little experience with WPF. I have an idea what can be done, but not much experience on how to get it done.

How do I check the `__postCloseAudit` check box through XAML based on the Text value of `__postCloseAuditBy`? If the Text length is greater than Zero, the check box should be checked.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="__postCloseAudit"
          Tag="{Binding LoginId}"
          Click="__postCloseAudit_Click">

    <WrapPanel>

        <TextBox x:Name="__postCloseAuditBy"
                 Width="94"
                 Text="{Binding PostCloseAuditBy }" />

        <TextBox x:Name="__postCloseAuditOn"
                 Width="132"
                 Text="{Binding PostCloseAuditOn }" />

    </WrapPanel>

</CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write a [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) and bind the [`IsChecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx) property to the text of the `TextBox`. The converter's job will be to take the text as an input and decide about the checked status based on its length; this will be in a separate class, so it's not exactly code-behind but it's close.

Example converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(bool?))]
public class TextToIsBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var s = (string)value;
        return s.Length > 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And the binding would look like:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="__postCloseAudit"
  Tag="{Binding LoginId}"
  Click="__postCloseAudit_Click"
  IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=__postCloseAuditBy, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}">
```

If you are using MVVM then your viewmodel should subsume the functionality of the converter and expose a calculated property based on the value of `PostCloseAuditBy`.

Comment: Never seen the attribute you use above the converter, what does it do?

Comment: @JohanLarsson: It's [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.valueconversionattribute.aspx). You don't *need* it, it has an informational role (the docs suggest that design-time tools can benefit by reflecting on the assembly containing the converter). I just lifted it off the MSDN example because it was already there.

Comment: @Jon; Interesting. I finally figured out I could use a converter, since that is as far as my knownledge goes. Yet, I never thought you could set the Path property to the Text property. But, in hindsight it makes perfect sense.

Comment: There was no use of a view-model; otherwise, it would have been easy. :O) I am stuck binding to the class (model).

Comment: @JohanLarsson; I use `ValueConversion` to make it obvious to the programer what the converter is intended for.